# Probability of process success

Tags: probability

Beforehand my pardon if I have some terminology mistakes since I'm not a mathematician.

I have a **process** that consist of multiple **activities**. Each **process** $S$ is described by milestones $(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n)$ that should be reached at the end of **process**. Conceptually **activity** is step of **process** that reaches  some subset of milestones. Each **activity** $a$ is represented by triplet: $(K, t, s)$

Where:

- K - some subset of $k_i$ milestones - for example $\{k_1, k_3\}$;
- t - total number of activity has been invoked;
- s - succeed number of activity invocation (so $s \leq t$);

The goal to estimate what is the probability of **process** success if this consists of predefined set of **activities** $$S = \{a_1, a_2 \ldots a_n\}$$ - it is guaranteed that $S$ fully covers process - so: $$\bigcup_{i}a_i = \{k_1, k_2...k_n\}$$ in other words we are sure that sequence of $a_i$ have no gaps in milestones and all milestones are passed after activities applied. The last note - activities are independent of each other (numbers $t, s$ have no correlation between activities).

**Live example:**

Let's assume the *Launch cooking* is a **process**. We have exactly 3 milestones for it:

- $k_1$ - prepare first dish;
- $k_2$ - prepare second dish;
- $k_3$ - prepare a dessert;

I have following activities:

- $a_1$ [*go & buy in supermarket*] (assume no soup in local one) then $K=\{k_2, k_3\}$. I have already tried this way and very glad with it so: $t=s=100$
- $a_2$ [*order in restaurant*] there every milestone is available $K={k_1, k_2, k_3}$. But unfortunately I have bad experience with restaurant delivery so $t=10, s=4$
- $a_3$ [*cook on my own*] I'm not an expert in desert cooking then $K=\{k_1, k_2\}$, also I'm good in cooking but mistakes happen, so $t=10, s=9$

So my question - what is the probability of a successful launch if I combine visiting the supermarket $a_1$ and cooking $a_3$ ? Trivial answer for $a_2$ - success probability is $s/t=4/10=0.4$ - it is clear for me, but how would one combine the probability of multiple activities?

Comment: what do you mean by $A$ fully covers the process? it seems that $A$ is made of triples $(K,t,s)$ so It lives in a different space than $K$ .  what is a sucess? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ConradoCosta - just edited in trying to clarify this (pay attention I've changed letter A->S) . In brief - I can grant that all milestones are passed after all activities are applied.

Comment: In a project you often want to set marks to  be sure that it can be accomplished in time. A milestone is a device, used to control the evolution of your project. eg:   build a house: in 01/2016  foundations , in 04/2016   rooms  in 07/2016  electrical parts and so on until the end. So a milestone($k_i$) comes with a due time ($s_i$){($k_1, 01$) ($k_2, 04$), ($k_3, 07), \ldots$} . Process success should be  to have all milestones met before due time. So if $s_i$ is the time you reach milestone $k_i$ then sucess of process is $s_i \leq t_i$. Am I on the right path?

Comment: Is it possible to chose activity $a_i$ and to have process success with just one activity?   Can you give an example that models your problem? With milestones, $t$ and $s$?

Comment: @ConradoCosta - I'm afraid that didn't get idea with dealing with time. So please review my update with **Live example**

Comment: you say that sucess probability in $a_2 = s/t=1$  but shouldn't it be success in $a_1 = 100/100 = 1$?

Comment: @ConradoCosta, yes my mistake it is 4/10=0.4, Just correct my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this helps:
If each activity has probability of success $p_i = \frac{s_i}{t_i}$ and you can reasonably assume that they are independent then $\mathbb{P}(\text{success } a_1 , a_2) = p_1 + p_2  - p_1 p_2$. This formula extends for $k$ activities by iteration Let ($p_{i_1,\ldots i_k}$ represent $\mathbb{P}(\text{success } a_{i_1}\ldots, a_{i_k})$):

$$\mathbb{P}(a_1, a_2,a_3) = p_{1,2,3} = p_1 + p_{2,3} - p_1 p_{2,3} = p_1 + p_2 + p_3 -p_2 p_3 - p_1(p_2 + p_3 -p_2 p_3) = p_1 +  p_2 + p_3 - p_2 p_3 -p_1p_2 -p_1p_3 + p_1p_2p_3 $$

$$\mathbb{P} (a_1,a_2,\ldots a_k) = \sum_{j \leq k} \sum_{i_1, \ldots i_j} (-1)^{j+1} p_{i_1} \ldots p_{i_j}$$

In the case where these events are not independent you might consider the general approach:

$$ \mathbb{P}(a_1 \cup a_2) = \mathbb{P}(a_1) + \mathbb{P}(a_2) - \mathbb{P}(a_1 \cap a_2)$$

Use the inclusion exclusion principle 
$$\mathbb{P} (\cup_{i=1}^k a_i) = \sum_{j \leq k} (-1)^{j+1} \sum_{i_1 ,\ldots i_j}\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i = 1}^j a_{i_j}) $$

in the case you would like to succeed in the entire process I would consider the probability of achieving each milestone at the time, that is,

consider the probability $p^j_l = \mathbb{P}(k_j \text{ succeeds  under } a_l)$ use the same arguments (of independence if it is reasonable or inclusion and exclusion principle plus a case by case consideration in case you suspect there are relevant interdependencies between milestones or activities)

Comment: Thank you for this response! It is look right, but before my approve let me ask: you wrote *...where these events **are not independent** you might consider the general approach...* Why do you use Inclusion–exclusion principle for depended instead of Bayes' theorem ?

Comment: It is likely you will  use Bayes in the next step: Let's see the case with 2 actions: 1^st step :$P(A \cup B) = P(A ) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. Bayes does not apply for the Union, but for the intersection, now you can use Bayes: $P(A \cap B) = P(A |B) P(B)$. Note that this generalizes for the case $k$: $$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_k) = P(A_1|A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_k) P(A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_k)$$.